# Как создать многоугольник в SVG

Tags: svg, inkscape

Хочу создать несколько сложных фигур (как в тетрисе) вплотную друг к другу с заливкой разным цветов. Всё это вместе образует план здания. Я так понял что мне нужен элемент polygon.
Использовал Inkscape но при выгрузке он вместо polygon превратил всё в несколько path. В чём лучше создавать фигуры, рисовать что-то что бы потом правильно экспортировать в SVG?

Answer (score 2):

Если, я правильно понял, возможно вы хотите заменить `<path>` на `<polygon>`, то это довольно просто, при условии, что ваша фигура состоит из прямых линий, которые образуют один замкнутый контур.

Ваша фигура будет записана примерно так:

```
<path .... d="M 60,20 100,40 100,80 60,100 20,80 20,40 Z" .... />
```

Все что нужно сделать - это взять содержимое атрибута `d`, удалить начало и конец (`M` и `Z`) и вставить это в атрибут points тега `<polygon>`:

```
<polygon points="60,20 100,40 100,80 60,100 20,80 20,40"/>
```

Координаты точек здесь записаны парами: `x,y` , если это не так, значит ваша фигура слишком сложная для `polygon` (возможно содержит кривые линии).

Хотя я не вижу объективных причин заменять `<path>` на `<polygon>`. По сути это тоже самое, но `<path>` имеет больше возможностей и по сути является самым многофункциональным инструментом.

**Вообще о том, как фигуры Inkscape соотносятся с фигурами SVG:**

В [стандарте SVG нет многих фигур](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element), которые есть в Inkscape. Такие фигуры как многоугольник, круг с вырезом, спираль и т.д., знает только Inkscape, для всех остальных приложений - это `<path>`.

Вот если взять пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я рисую многоугольник, в редакторе SVG он сразу отображается как `<path>`. Но в отличие от обычных `<path>` он отображается с дополнительными атрибутами, начинающимися с `sodipodi:...` и `inkscape:...`.

Когда Inkscape видит эти аттрибуты, он понимает, что перед ним не просто `<path>`, а многоугольник.  Для любой другой программы эти атрибуты бесполезны и совершенно не влияют на отображение многоугольника, поскольку все координаты точек заданы в атрибуте `d`. А Inkscape, наоборот, не использует `d`, но создает этот атрибут для совместимости с другими приложениями.

Таким образом, когда вы сохраняете документ как "Inkscape svg" он сохраняет эти атрибуты, а когда "Простой svg" — он опускает их (и многие другие) не сохраняя информацию, бесполезную для других приложений.